# A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'NDde!NDde.Foundation.Ddeml+DdeCallback::Invoke'.

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, garbage-collection, dde

I have a WPF application and we open Avaya dialer application using a DDE(Dynamic Data Exchange). It launches fine for two or three times, But when we launch for 4th time, sometimes after a long gap, I find the below error.

“A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'NDde!NDde.Foundation.Ddeml+DdeCallback::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.”

Below is the code for this. You can find full code in https://ndde.codeplex.com/
Please help me find the root cause and resolve it.

```
 //call back declared here
     internal static class Ddeml
        {
      public delegate IntPtr DdeCallback(
                int uType, int uFmt, IntPtr hConv, IntPtr hsz1, IntPtr hsz2, IntPtr hData, IntPtr dwData1, IntPtr dwData2);
    }


        internal sealed class DdemlContext : IDisposable
        {    
 private int  _InstanceId   = 0;     // DDEML instance identifier
            private Ddeml.DdeCallback _Callback   = null  ; 


        public DdemlContext()
        {

            // Create the callback that will be used by the DDEML.
            _Callback = new Ddeml.DdeCallback(this.OnDdeCallback);
        }


            private IntPtr OnDdeCallback(int uType, int uFmt, IntPtr hConv, IntPtr hsz1, IntPtr hsz2, IntPtr hData, IntPtr dwData1, IntPtr dwData2)
            {
                // Create a new transaction object that will be dispatched to a DdemlClient, DdemlServer, or ITransactionFilter.
                DdemlTransaction t = new DdemlTransaction(uType, uFmt, hConv, hsz1, hsz2, hData, dwData1, dwData2);

                // Run each transaction filter.
                foreach (IDdemlTransactionFilter filter in _Filters)
                {
                    if (filter.PreFilterTransaction(t))
                    {
                        return t.dwRet;
                    }
                }

                // Dispatch the transaction.
                switch (uType)
                {
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_ADVDATA:
                    {
                        DdemlClient client = _ClientTable[hConv] as DdemlClient;
                        if (client != null)
                        {
                            if (client.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_ADVREQ:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_ADVSTART:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_ADVSTOP:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_CONNECT:
                    {
                        // Get the service name from the hsz2 string handle.
                        StringBuilder psz = new StringBuilder(Ddeml.MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                        int length = Ddeml.DdeQueryString(_InstanceId, hsz2, psz, psz.Capacity, Ddeml.CP_WINANSI);
                        string service = psz.ToString();

                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable2[service] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_CONNECT_CONFIRM:
                    {
                        // Get the service name from the hsz2 string handle.
                        StringBuilder psz = new StringBuilder(Ddeml.MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                        int length = Ddeml.DdeQueryString(_InstanceId, hsz2, psz, psz.Capacity, Ddeml.CP_WINANSI);
                        string service = psz.ToString();

                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable2[service] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            _ServerTable1[hConv] = server;
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_DISCONNECT:
                    {
                        DdemlClient client = _ClientTable[hConv] as DdemlClient;
                        if (client != null)
                        {
                            _ClientTable[hConv] = null;
                            if (client.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            _ServerTable1[hConv] = null;
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_EXECUTE:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_POKE:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_REQUEST:
                    {
                        DdemlServer server = _ServerTable1[hConv] as DdemlServer;
                        if (server != null)
                        {
                            if (server.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_XACT_COMPLETE:
                    {
                        DdemlClient client = _ClientTable[hConv] as DdemlClient;
                        if (client != null)
                        {
                            if (client.ProcessCallback(t))
                            {
                                return t.dwRet;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_WILDCONNECT:
                    {
                        // This library does not support wild connects.
                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_MONITOR:
                    {
                        // Monitors are handled separately in DdemlMonitor.
                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_ERROR:
                    {
                        // Get the error code, but do nothing with it at this time.
                        int error = dwData1.ToInt32();

                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_REGISTER:
                    {
                        if (Register != null)
                        {
                            // Get the service name from the hsz1 string handle.
                            StringBuilder psz = new StringBuilder(Ddeml.MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                            int length = Ddeml.DdeQueryString(_InstanceId, hsz1, psz, psz.Capacity, Ddeml.CP_WINANSI);
                            string service = psz.ToString();

                            Register(this, new DdemlRegistrationEventArgs(service));
                        }
                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    case Ddeml.XTYP_UNREGISTER:
                    {
                        if (Unregister != null)
                        {
                            // Get the service name from the hsz1 string handle.
                            StringBuilder psz = new StringBuilder(Ddeml.MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                            int length = Ddeml.DdeQueryString(_InstanceId, hsz1, psz, psz.Capacity, Ddeml.CP_WINANSI);
                            string service = psz.ToString();

                            Unregister(this, new DdemlRegistrationEventArgs(service));
                        }
                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                }           
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
```

Comment: About 90% of this code is irrelevant. What is missing is the lifecycle management of the DdemlContext instances.

Comment: Even static members can be garbage collected. Find a way to keep a reference to it in the instanced class or something similar

Comment: Thank you Henk :) It helped. I understood that DdemlContext is not properly disposed when the avaya application is closed. So when we reopen it the debugger is pointing to the callback.